# Disable the button partially

Tags: asp.net

I I'm using Raddatetimepicker to select began and enddate.
When user select two dates then he can click the button called fiter.
I want to show partially(it should appear when page load but in inactive mode) the button before user select the both end and began date. once he selected the both dates i should 
show the button as activated.
How can I do it.
Please help me.

Comment: Some of your code would help others visualise what you were asking

Answer (score 0):

get two bool variables which are set false on Startup, set them true on each pick, if both true show button (visible=true or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

just Disable the Filter button on window loads or initially in the Properties of the Filter Button  ..use events to enable and disable the Filter button Dont use Visible==false as it may not seen when loads but if you use disabled the button can visible but it can't be clickable  and using  event you can  enbale the filtet button using simple cade as

`btnFilter.Enabled=true;`

Comment: Yes. But how to know the date is selected or not of raddatimepicker. Which raddatetimepicer event will fire when i selcted the date.